# Regular expression to add namespace prefix in xml

Tags: java, regex, preg-match

I am stuck at one point.I have a xml which does not have a prefix.
I am trying to put the prefix through Regular expression.
My xml looks as below:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tier="http://xxxx">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tier:UnisysMB_Dispatch>
     <PayLoad>
    <XMLTransaction>
        <Source_Identifier>WFM.MSM.SR</Source_Identifier>
        </XMLTransaction></PayLoad>
  </tier:UnisysMB_Dispatch>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but I want the xml with namespace prefix with every tag (s1) like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:tier="http://xxxx" s1="someurl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tier:UnisysMB_Dispatch>
     <s1:PayLoad>
    <s1:XMLTransaction>
        <s1:Source_Identifier>WFM.MSM.SR</s1:Source_Identifier>
        <s1:/XMLTransaction></s1:PayLoad>
  </tier:UnisysMB_Dispatch>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried this 
search regex ="(<\/?)[a-z0-9]+";
replace =s1:"$1"
but not working..

any help please??

Comment: Where comes `preg_match` in java? Don't parse xml files with regex.

Comment: I included because Regular expression is common topic among all, so anyone can help me..I am sorry to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `(</?)(\w+)>` with `$1s1:$2>`. Now this should only work fine in your IDE.

For the first line you have to use another regex. `(<soapenv:Envelope.*?)>` by `$1 s1="someUrl">`.

I agree with other comments, that regex parsing is not the best way to extract information from XML. Actually this is not parsing, but replacing. This should work for small examples.

If you are in need for a robust solution that works for a variable number of WSDLs, you should switch to an XML parser/rewriter. I think that some XML-Tools support your problem out of the box.

Comment: This will at least have some issues related to the "tier:" and "soapenv:" texts, and potentially also with the Source_Identifier by the first look of it. This does however illustrate the point of regex on xml is not good...

Comment: You should have tried it out before claiming that it does not work.

Comment: it works with basic shot..but let me have more testing with different values...Thank you very much....Stefan